# Passenger - Using "Requests in queue" as an AWS metric for autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, autoscaling

I am surprised to find little information regarding EC2 autoscaling with Phusion Passenger.

I actually discovered not so long ago a metric "Requests in queue" being exposed upon running `passenger-status`

I am wondering whether this stat would make a nice metric to help with autoscaling.

Right now most AWS EC2 Autoscaling guides mention using CPU and Memory to write autoscaling rules but I find this insufficient. When I think about the problem autoscaling should solve, that is being able to scale up to the demand, I'd rather base those rules on the number of pending/completed requests to report a node health or a cluster congestion, and Passenger "Requests in queue" (and also for each process, the "Last Used" and "Processed" count) seems to useful.

I am wondering it it would be possible to report this "Requests in queue" stat (and eventually others) periodically as an AWS metric. I was thinking the following rule would be ideal for autoscaling : If the average number of "requests in queue" on the autoscaled instances is to exceed a threshold value, this would trigger spawning a new machine from the autoscaling group.

Is this possible ? 
Has anyone ever tried to implement autoscaling rules based on number of requests in queue this way ?

Answer (score 6):

This is totally possible (and a good approach).

**Step 1.** Create custom CloudWatch metric for "Requests in queue".
You will have to write your own agent that runs `passenger-status`, extracts the value and sends it to CloudWatch. You can use any AWS SDK or just AWS CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html

**Step 2.** Create alarms for scale up and scale down based on your custom metric.

**Step 3.** Modify scaling policy for your Auto Scaling Group to use your custom alarms to scale up/down.